# Use two listeners of FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I want to modify some form fields depending on submitted data so in the form class I did:

```php
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('year', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => ['Year' => '-1'] + array_combine(range(date('Y'), date('Y') - 19), range(date('Y'), date('Y') - 19)),
                'label' => false,
            ])
            ->add('make', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => ['Make' => '-1'], 'label' => false])
            ->add('model', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => ['Model' => '-1'], 'label' => false]);

        //...

        $builder->get('year')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $year = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $makes = $year === '-1' ? ['Make' => '-1'] : $this->customService->getMakes();
                $event->getForm()->getParent()
                    ->add('make', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => $makes, 'label' => false]);
            }
        );
        $builder->get('make')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $make = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $models = $make === '-1'  ? ['Model' => '-1'] : $this->customService->getModels();
                $event->getForm()->getParent()
                    ->add('model', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => $models, 'label' => false]);
            }
        );
    }
```

However, even when I submit the `make` field, the second listener is never executed, so I'm not able to modify the `model` field. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that when modifying the `make` field in the `year` field event listener, then the `make` field event listener is never called. I found a way to make it work:

```php
    private $makes;
    private $models;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //...

        $builder->get('year')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $year = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $this->makes = $year === '-1' ? ['Make' => '-1'] : $this->customService->getMakes();
            }
        );
        $builder->get('make')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $make = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $this->models = $make === '-1'  ? ['Model' => '-1'] : $this->customService->getModels();
                $event->getForm()->getParent()
                    ->add('make', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => $this->makes, 'label' => false, 'data' => $make]);
            }
        );
        // Same with model field
    }
```